# A lack of understanding of convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, fake-proofs

I read somewhere that if we have $X_n \Rightarrow X$ and $Y_n \Rightarrow Y$ it does not implies $X_n + Y_n \Rightarrow X + Y$ (where $\Rightarrow$ means weak convergence/convergence in distribution).

Unfortunately it seems that I "proved" this fact and even worse it seems that I proved that for every continuous function f from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ we will have $f(X_n,Y_n) \Rightarrow f(X,Y)$ which cannot be true.

I used a result from Durrett "Probability: Theory and examples" (Theorem 3.2.8 of version 5a).

"If $F_n \Rightarrow F$ then there is a sequence of random variables $Y_n$ with distribution $F_n$ so that $Y_n \rightarrow Y$ a.s where $Y$ has distribution $F$."

Hence I can find $\tilde{X}_n \rightarrow \tilde{X} $ a.s and $\tilde{Y}_n \rightarrow \tilde{Y}$ a.s where $\tilde{X}_n,\tilde{Y}_n,\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}$ have the same distribution as $X_n,Y_n,X,Y$. Now, for every bounded continuous function g, since g and f are continuous, we have $g(f(\tilde{X}_n,\tilde{Y}_n)) \rightarrow g(f(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}))$ a.s  and since g is bounded by the dominated convergence theorem :

$\mathbb{E}[g(f(X_n,Y_n))] = \mathbb{E}[g(f(\tilde{X}_n,\tilde{Y}_n))] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[g(f(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}))] = \mathbb{E}[g(f(X,Y))]$

And hence, $f(X_n,Y_n) \Rightarrow f(X,Y)$.

I can't find where my reasoning fails.

Comment: Do you have any justification for assuming that $\tilde X_n,\tilde Y_n$ is *jointly* distributed like $X_n,Y_n$?

Comment: Mmh I see, so X is distributed as $\tilde{X}$ and Y as $\tilde{Y}$ does not imply (X,Y) is distributed as $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$ ?

Comment: It does not. Classic counterexample: Let $X,Y$ be independently and identically distributed RVs (say normal, but the details don't matter so long as the distribution is non-degenerate).  Then let $\tilde X = X$ and $\tilde Y = X.$

Comment: The theorem you have quoted (due to Skorohod) is useful only in some very special circumstances. It is dangerous to use it without proper understanding of joint distributions and independence. I suggest you ignore this theorem for the time being.

Comment: Ignore Skorokhod? What a strange suggestion... If you follow carefully what Skorokhod is providing in your setting, you should see that it is the existence of $X'_n$, $Y'_n$, $X'$ and $Y'$, distributed ike $X_n$, $Y_n$, $X$ and $Y$ respectively, such that $X'_n\to X'$ and $Y'_n\to Y'$ almost surely. Then of course, $f(X'_n,Y'_n)\to f(X',Y')$ almost surely, for every given $f$... But this says nothing about $f(X_n,Y_n)$ and $f(X,Y)$, right? Note that the fact that $(X'_n,Y'_n)$ or $(X',Y')$ has the same distribution as $(X_n,Y_n)$ or $(X,Y)$ is not guaranteed.